# how to pass a string to a mixin and generate a dynamic variable to output color in LESSCSS?

Tags: css, less

```
  //call the mixin 
  .mixin-loop(grey, 7);

  //the implementation
  .mixin-loop(@str, @count) {
    .loop (@i) when (@i > 0) {

      .@{str}-@{i} {
        div { background: "@{@{str}-@{i}}"; }
      }
      .loop(@i - 1);
    }
    .loop (@count);
  }

//globals.less
@grey-1: #ccc;
@grey-2: #999;
```

The output I want is this:

```
//output
.grey-1 div {
  background: #ccc;
}

.grey-2 div {
  background: #999;
}
```

But what I'm getting is this:

```
.#808080-1 div {
  background: "@{#808080-1}";
}
.#808080-2 div {
  background: "@{#808080-2}";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variable interpolation (`~`) to help with this:

http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-interpolation

This will prevent `grey` from being converted into it's hex value, and then will allow `"@{@{str}-@{i}}"` to be displayed as a hex value instead of a string.

```
  //call the mixin 
  .mixin-loop(~"grey", 2);

  //the implementation
  .mixin-loop(@str, @count) {
    .loop (@i) when (@i > 0) {

        .@{str}-@{i} {
            div { background: ~"@{@{str}-@{i}}"; }
      }
      .loop(@i - 1);
    }
    .loop (@count);
  }

//globals.less
@grey-1: #ccc;
@grey-2: #999;
```